# How to solve $x(x-1)(x+2)>0$ for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am confused by this question. My book says, $x(x-1)(x+2)>0$ means x is in the range $(-2,0)\cup(1,\infty)$.

I can't find anything on how to deal with an inequality where x is displayed in this way. I could multiply $x(x-1)(x+2)$ to create $x^3+x^2-2x>0$ but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

I feel like there must be a rule I've forgotten about why $x(x-1)(x+2)>0$ means x is in the range $(-2,0)\cup(1,\infty)$, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Study the sign of each factor and compare them from then on.

Comment: If $-2<x<0$ then $x$ and $x-1$ are negative and $x+2$ is positive, so the product of all three is positive, etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown why do you say $-2<x<0$? Can I figure it out by putting each term like $x+2>0$, $x - 1 > 0$, $x > 0$ etc?

Comment: have you done sign analysis before?

Comment: @AniruddhVenkatesan I don't recognize the name, but I might've forgotten it. I am doing review for calc1 and my algebra class barely covered inequalities.

Comment: @LuminousNutria you solve for the zeroes(roots) of the inequality. Then plug in values in each specific to determine whether the function is positive or negative on that interval

Comment: These "rules" and "algorithms" are all good.  But this isn't magic and the rules aren't incantations.  $x(x-1)(x+2)$ is a product of three factors.  And for a product of factors to be positive it most but that only an even number of factors are negative and the rest positive.  So set the smallest even number of factors negative and the rest positive and solve. Either $x-1,x,x+2$ are all positive.  Or $x-1, x$ are negative and $x+2$ is positive.  No magical incantation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if we think it out:

If $abc > 0$ is positive then of the eight possible combinations of $a,b,c$ being positive of negative we have to ask ourselves when will we get a result that is is positive and when will we get a result that is negative and when will we get a result that is zero?

Well, if any of $a,b,c$ are zero the whole thing is $0$.  so if $abc > 0$ then none of $a,b,c$ are $0$.

If all $a,b,c$ are positive the $abc$ is positive.  So that's possible.

If two are positive and one is negative then the $abc$ is negative and that is not possible.

If one is positive and two are negative then $abc$ is positive and that is possible.

And if all three are negative then $abc$ is negative and that isn't possible.

So if $abc > 0$ then either $a,b,c$ are all positive or one of $a,b,c$ is positive and the other two are negative.

Now $x - 1 < x < x+2$ so if $x(x-1)(x+2)$ then either:

1) The all are positive.  So $x-1 > 0; x > 0; $ and $x +2 > 0$ so $x > 1$ and $x > 0$ and $x > -2$ .  But that's redundant.

It would have been good enough to just take the smallest so $x - 1 > 0$ and $x > 1$.

That's enough.

...or...

2) One is positive and the other are negative.  As $x + 2$ is the largest of the three, $x+2$ is the one that is positive and the other two $x, x -1$ must be negative.

So $x + 2 > 0$ and $x < 0$ and $x -1 < 0$ so $x>-2$ and $x < 0$ and $x< 1$.

Combining we get: $-2 < x < 0$.

Note: As $x -1 < x$ it was redundant to consider it; we didn't need to consider it.

So if $x > 1$ or if $-2 < x < 0$ we will get $x(x-1)(x+2) > 0$.

......

Another way of putting it.  $x, x-1,$ and $x+2$ will change positive values when we $x$ is in different intervals.

Case 1:  $x > 1$ then $x > 0$ and $x -1> 0$ and $x + 2> 0$ so $x(x-1)(x+2) > 0$.  GOOD.

Case 2: $x = 1$  then $x-1=0$ and $x(x-1)(x+2) =0$.  BAD.

Case 3: $0 < x < 1$ then $x-1 < 0$ and $x > 0$ and $x+2 > 0$ and so $x(x-1)(x+2) < 0$.  BAD.

Case 4: $x = 0$ then $x(x-1)(x+2) = 0$.  BAD.

Case 5:  $-2 < x < 0$ then $x-1 < 1; x < 0$ and $x + 2 > 0$ and $x(x-1)(x+2) > 0$.  GOOD.

Case 6: $x = -2$ then $x+2 = 0$ and $x(x-1)(x+2) = 0$.  BAD.

Case 7: $x < -2$.  Then $x < 0; x-1 < 0; x+2 < 0$ and $x(x-1)(x+2) < 0$.  BAD.

So only 1 and 5 are GOOD so $-2< x < 0$ or $x > 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+2),$ a product of 3 terms.   Clearly, $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x \in \{0,1,-2\}$.

Therefore, we consider the following intervals separately:
$(-\infty,-2), (-2,0), (0,1),$ and $(1,\infty).$

When $x \in (-\infty,-2), f(x) < 0$, since it is a product of three negative terms.

When $x \in (-2,0), f(x) > 0,$ since $x+2$ is positive and the other terms are negative.

When $x \in (0,1), f(x) < 0,$ since $x-1$ is negative and the other terms are positive.

Finally, when $x \in (1,\infty), f(x) > 0,$ since it is a product of three positive terms.

Thus, the answer is $f(x)> 0$ when $-x \in (-2,0) \cup (1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general with inequalities it's a matter of considering each case separately. For this problem, the cases can be intervals on which the sign of $x(x-1)(x+2)$ doesn't change.

(I'll try to explain the process rather than give the answer, because I want you to be able to get there yourself.)

First we need to find the intervals on which none of the  three factors of the expression changes sign. Once we've done that, we can check whether it's positive or negative on each interval.

For a factor to change sign, it must pass through zero. So we proceed like this:

- Find the values of $x$ for which $x=0$, $x-1=0$, or $x+2=0$. (Obviously these are $0,1$ and $-2$.)
- Use these to divide the real line up into intervals.
- For each interval, check what sign each of $x$, $x-1$ and $x+2$ will have.

That immediately gives you the sign of $x(x-1)(x+2)$ on each interval, and all you need do is pick the intervals where it's positive.

**Shortcut for this example:**  Between one interval and the next, exactly one factor of the original expression changes sign. That's because they're all zero in different places, and because they're all linear (so any which is zero must be changing sign).

So the sign alternates from one interval to the next, and you can get it for all four intervals by checking just one.

But normally, each interval needs examining separately to be absolutely sure of the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this separately rather than clutter up my other answer. I think this is the quickest method, though not the quickest to explain. It uses the shortcut from my other answer.

Let $y=x(x-1)(x+2)$.

Notice that:

- if $x, (x-1)$ or $(x+2)$ is zero, it is changing sign from negative to positive.
- if one factor of $y$ changes sign, so does $y$.
- the three factors are zero at different values of $x$, namely $-2,0$ and $1$. So only one changes sign at a time.

So $y$ changes sign at $x=-2$, $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Before any factor has changed sign, all three are negative, making $y$ negative. So $y$ is

- negative for $x<-2$
- positive for $-2<x<0$
- negative for $0<x<1$
- positive for $x>1$

at which point all three factors have changed from negative to positive.

And the intervals on which $y$ is positive combine as $(-2,0)\cup (1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the product of two positive number is positive, as is the product of two negative numbers, whereas the product of a positive and negative number is negative. Considering $x(x-1)(x+2) > 0$, then, we can replace $a=x$, $b=x-1$, $c=x+2$.

1. Suppose $a > 0$. Then $bc > 0$ as well so that $b$ and $c$ are either both positive or both negative.

   - If $b > 0$, we must have $c > 0$.
   - If $b < 0$, we must have $c < 0$.
2. Suppose $a < 0$. Then $bc < 0$ as well, so that one of $b$ and $c$ is negative and the other is positive.

   - If $b > 0$, we must have $c < 0$.
   - If $b < 0$, we must have $c > 0$.

We have here enumerated all possible choices for $a$, $b$, and $c$. Apply this in the context of your specific problem to see what limitations are then placed on $x$.

1. If $x>0$, then $(x-1)(x+2) > 0$ as well.

   - If $x - 1 > 0$ (i.e. $x > 1$), then $x + 2 > 0$ (i.e. $x > -2$).

     - Putting these all together says that that $x> -2$, $x > 0$, and $x > 1$, all of which can be simultaneously true, as long as $x > 1$, giving us that $x \in (1,\infty)$ is acceptable.
   - If $x - 1 < 0$ (i.e. $x < 1$), then $x + 2 < 0$ (i.e. $x < -2$).

     - Putting these all together says that that $x < -2$, $x > 0$, and $x > 1$, all of which can **not** be simultaneously true (show me a number that is both less than -2 and greater than 1 (hint: you can't)).
2. I'll leave the case when $x < 0$ up to you.